# Explain what is "wine dependency hell" when using WINE for windows software?

Tags: wine, dependencies

I use Ubuntu 18.04. I play games using lutris and steam with proton. I've read some people warn against "wine dependency hell". What is this and how can I avoid this?

When I try to get games running in Lutris, I typically just use the script they provide on their site for said game. Otherwise I stumble around in Lutris, it fully understanding what I'm doing, hoping to get the game working.

Comment: I searched the net for the phrase and the first hit maybe of interest to you: https://www.gloriouseggroll.tv/how-to-get-out-of-wine-dependency-hell/

Comment: I remember hearing about that site. Thanks I think that answers it! How do I mark this as solved and give you the credit? I don't fully understand how to use this site....

Comment: Oh @DKBose needs to make an answer ;-)

Comment: But I don't use Wine and haven't run into *any* sort of dependency hell so far. @BingBong, please post an answer yourself.